# Multiple instances of jQuery plugin (Magnific popup)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've hit a bit of a wall with this one. My jQuery knowledge outside of just implementation is pretty poor.

I'm building the Magnific Popup (http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) jQuery plugin into my WordPress theme as a popup gallery. I've got it all wired up and working. It grabs images dynamically from the backend using custom fields. I can also get multiple instances working on the same page. HOWEVER, when scrolling through images in one popup gallery, it wont end at the end of the first gallery but rather, it will move on into the images in the second gallery. See example: http://www.oftenvisual.com/reset/galleries/.

Unfortunately I can't post the code here as it's too long, but hopefully the demo page helps. Because the galleries are generated dynamically and the client using the backend wont have the knowledge to add container with different classes, I need some way to also dynamically separate out the galleries. Any idea GREATLY appreciated!

Script calling the plugin

```
// Magnific

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.popup-gallery').magnificPopup({
            delegate: 'a',
            type: 'image',
            tLoading: 'Loading image #%curr%...',
            mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
            gallery: {
                enabled: true,
                navigateByImgClick: true,
                preload: [0,1] // Will preload 0 - before current, and 1 after the current image
            },
            image: {
                tError: '<a href="%url%">The image #%curr%</a> could not be loaded.',
                titleSrc: function(item) {
                    return item.el.attr('title');
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: [Please don't post links to your website](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [jquery's each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) with the same class, for example:

```
$('.popup-gallery').each(function() {
      $(this).magnificPopup({
        delegate: 'a', // child items selector, by clicking on it popup will open
        type: 'image', // override with class 'mfp-iframe' on delegate or any other supported type
        gallery: {enabled:true },
      });
});
```

And now if you have multiple .popup-gallery divs, they all work separately.

Answer (score 0):

try to set different id_s on your .popup-gallery div's and then do

```
$('#popup-gallery1').magnificPopup....

$('#popup-gallery2').magnificPopup....
```

Comment: Thanks for the insanely quick reply. However, just realised I've been a bit of an idiot and not properly read the documentation... http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#gallery. The plugin author has already covered this and I just needed to change the first few lines of the script that calls the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You may use jQuery contains selector to point "a" tag with specific class name - **a[class*='popup-gallery-']**. If you have different IDs for you pop-ups it just work as a charm. It just search for all "a" where class contains "popup-gallery-".
And if it matches, it fires up the Magnific Pop Up etc.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("a[class*='popup-gallery-']").magnificPopup({ 
        //your settings goes here
 });
});
```

HTML:

```
# first div
<a class="popup-gallery-1" href="#popup-1">First popup</a>
<div id="popup-1"> Your content here </div>

# second div
<a class="popup-gallery-2" href="#popup-2">Second popup</a>
<div id="popup-2"> Your content here </div>
```